# In SQLite, how do I search my database with text from an entry box, and display the result as text?

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlite

I have an Entry box on my search page. I want this function to search the table (movies) in my database for whatever text (column name is 'title') was entered into that Entry box, and then display the result.

```
def search_now():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('movie_catalog.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    searched = search_box.get()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title = %s"
    name = (searched, )
    result = c.execute(sql, name)

    if not result:
        result = "Movie not found"


    # Commit our changes
    conn.commit()

    # Close database connection
    conn.close()
```

I keep getting the following error message:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
```

The tutorial I've been using is using MYSql, so I'm not sure if  the "%s" placeholder applies or not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should either do this (not safe)

```py
searched = search_box.get()
sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title = '%s'" % searched
result = c.execute(sql)
```

or this (fairly secure against injections)

```py
searched = search_box.get()
t = (searched,)
sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title=?"
result = c.execute(sql, t)
```

EDIT:

- In your example you are passing the literal string `SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title = '%s'"` to the database, this is why it is complaining about the `%s`

Comment: Perfect, that worked like a charm. Thanks so much, I appreciate it!